# How to catch odd numbers using switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, fall-through

The following code should print whether intenger value is odd or even with fall through switch statement and for statements

```
for(int i=2; i<=10; i+=2)
{

  switch(i)
  {
    case 1: 
    {System.out.printf("\nNot printing odd numbers");}
    case 2: 
      System.out.printf("\n %d is an even number.", i);
    //case 3:
    //case 4: 

  }//end switch

}//end for
```

Comment: Why do you want to use switch?

Comment: @AniketKulkarni my prof ask me to, but i dont know how to deal with it.

Comment: this should be the output. it just dont get to me.
Not printing odd numbers!
\n 2 is an even number.
Not printing odd numbers!
\n 4 is an even number.
Not printing odd numbers!
\n6 is an even number.
Not printing odd numbers!
\n8 is an even number.
Not printing odd numbers!
\n10 is an even number.

Comment: None of the responses uses fall-through technique though.

Comment: @Voicu there's no need to use fall-through for this case. What will happen if somebody changes 10 to 100 later and the code should still verify if `i` is odd or even? You won't write fall-through until 99...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Bryan is asked (probably homework) to use fall-through though.

Comment: @Voicu You might've mixed up people here; I don't see a Bryan anywhere.

Comment: @DennisMeng: I was referring to the OP, who changed names meanwhile.

Comment: @Voicu Ordinarily I'd assume something like that happened; it's just that I don't really expect a name change from "Bryan" to "Linda"

Answer (score 8):

Change `i+=2` to `i++` and `i+=2` will give you value of `i` as `2,4,6,8,10` which means only even numbers.

```
switch(i%2)
  {
  case 0:
     //even number
     break;
  case 1:
     //Odd Number
     break;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need given your `for` loop,

```
for(int i=2; i<=10; i+=2)
```

`i` will not be odd. Based on your `switch` and problem statement I think you wanted,

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  switch(i) {
  case 2: case 4: case 6: case 8: case 10: 
    System.out.printf("\n %d is an even number.", i);
    break;
  default:
    System.out.printf("\nNot printing odd numbers");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe a fall-through switch should look like this. I have ommitted your outer for loop for simplicity.

```
  switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 9:
        System.out.printf("\nNot printing odd numbers");
     break;

        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 8:
        System.out.printf("\n %d is an even number.", i);
     break;
}
```

You essentially Fallthrough some cases (all odd numbers and all even numbers). Hence the term. You can read more about [fallthrough here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).

Answer (score 1):

```
     for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {

            switch (i % 2) {
            case 0: // even number
                System.out.printf("\n %d is an even number.", i);
                break;
            case 1: // odd number
                System.out.printf("\nNot printing odd numbers");
                break;          

            }// end switch

        }// end for
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {

            switch (i % 2) {

            case 0:
                System.out.printf("\n%d is an even number.", i);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.printf("\nNot printing odd numbers");
                break;

          }// end switch

        }// end for
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nt num=10;//any number you want
nt last=num%10;
        switch(last)
         {
                 case 0:
                 case 2:
                 case 4:
                 case 6:
                 case 8:
                System.out.println("numbet is even" +num) ;
                   break ;
                   default :
                System.out.println("number is odd" +num)
           } 
             //end of switch block
            //odd or even using fall through language java
            //GAGAN GANJWAR
```